# How do I add geolocation to this code?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geolocation, marker

I am currently trying to add geolocation functionality to the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var marker;
var infowindow;

function initialize() {
  var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(51.507059, -0.122631);
  var options = {
    zoom: 14,
    center: latlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), options);
  var html = &quot;<table/>&quot; +
             &quot;<tr><td>Name:</td><td><input id='name' type='text'/></td></tr>&quot; +
      &quot;<tr><td><br/>Description:</td><td><input id='description' type='text'/></td></tr>&quot; +
      &quot;<tr><td/><td><br/><center><input onclick='saveData()' type='button' value='Save &amp; Close'/></center></td></tr>&quot;;
infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
 content: html
});

google.maps.event.addListener(map, "click", function(event) {
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: event.latLng,
      map: map
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
    });
});
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, &#39;load&#39;, initialize);

</script>
```

Geolocation Code:

```
// HTML5 geolocation
if(navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
    var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,
                                   position.coords.longitude);

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        map: map,
        position: pos,
        content: 'Location found using HTML5.'
    });

    map.setCenter(pos);
    }, function() {
    handleNoGeolocation(true);
    });
} else {
    // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
    handleNoGeolocation(false);
}
}

function handleNoGeolocation(errorFlag) {
if (errorFlag) {
    var content = 'Error: Locations services failed.';
} else {
    var content = 'Error: Your browser doesn\'t support geolocation.';
}

var options = {
    map: map,
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(51.507059, -0.122631),
    content: content
};

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(options);
map.setCenter(options.position);
}
```

However, when I attempt to merge the initialize functions, I get the error 'Cannot read property '_*e3*' of undefined.' If I keep the functions separate, the program simply ignores the geolocation code. So, I'm stuck, and was hoping someone could give me a hand. Thanks a million!

*Note: I have tried everything relevant at https://developers.google.com/maps/, and have checked through all of the very similar questions on this site - this is not a duplicate post. Also, please ignore my use of HTML character codes inside the JavaScript - it's the only way to get HTML (infowindow) inside JavaScript (code) inside HTML (webdata) working.*

Comment: What does your code look like where you tried to combine the functionality and failed?  Can you provide a fiddle that exhibits the problem?  Your problem almost certainly has to do with the asynchronous nature of the geolocation functionality.

Comment: You will have to make variable `map` global, at least.